# Replication between two Cloud Services

Tags: sql-server, oracle, replication, aws

Is it possible to implement SQL Server Replication between two disparate cloud services?

For instance, if I have an instance running in Amazon's AWS Cloud Service and another instance running in Oracle's OCI Cloud Service, can I use SQL Server Replication to replicate data between both services in a master-master approach?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to implement SQL Replication between SQL RDS in AWS Cloud Service and SQL Database in OCI Cloud Service?

It can be, depending on the service types used. How to do that will entirely depend on your configuration, setup, and cloud services (in some configurations and services it may not be possible).